# Clean up rows from persistent log in session table?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, authentication, persistence

I've got a table called `user_sessions` where I store the `id`, `user_id`, `series_id` and `key` from users who have opted to stay logged in after they re-open their browsers. Upon opting for it, a cookie with the same data (except `id`) is stored on the client's browser. I've set the expiration time to be exactly **90** days after the cookie has been issued.

I'm wondering **how** or even **if** I should keep this table clean. There are some scenarios where it could contain rows that are redundant. If I don't clean it up, it could get bloated very fast.

When a user explicitly logs out of the application the cookie will be destroyed if any exist and the corresponding row (based on the cookie's `series_id`) if it matches any.

But when the cookie data has been altered or deleted (by something *other* then my application) from the client's browser, the corresponding table row will become redundant and my application won't be able to know that it should be deleted, because it has no way to distinguish an actively used row from one that's redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding a column that stores the date that the row was created and regularly delete rows older than 90 days, or whatever the cookie expiration is.

By the way, I hope you're using HTTPS and secure cookies to avoid session hijacking from sniffing or impersonation.